# Network drive auto reconnect on Windows 8.1/10

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2

I have `file server`, `workstation` in domain network and `GPO` (map network drive to users).

`File server` based on `Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard` (similarly with `Windows Server 2008 R2`).
`Workstation` based on `Windows 8.1` or `Windows 10` (I tries on some different PCs).

After OS startup, GPO successfully execute and network drive is mapped.
Later, this network drive will auto reconnects every X minutes. I have programs, which run from network drive, and when drive reconnect - my apps is crash.

**Workstation based on Windows XP or Windows 7 - doesn't have this problem.**

On Windows Server session from my PC is open (from time PC is startup).
On workstation in event logs I find only error from app about crash itself.

**What problem with Windows 8.1/10 and how I can fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want the drives to stay mapped and not disconnect and reconnect? I can't tell based on how you worded your question,

If that is what you want, you can try mapping in the format:

```
net use l: \\server\share\folder\etc persistent:yes
```